# how to safely register std::stop_callback with std::jthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I'm a bit confused about how to safely register callbacks for `jthread`. You need the `token` so that means that you would need to do the registration after creating the `jthread` which means that the callback would be destroyed before the `jthread`. In the example below `cb5` and `cb6` obviously get destroyed before the dtor of the `jthread` starts so they automatically deregister themselves and never execute. Conversely, `cb1` and `cb2` are explicitly destroyed after the destruction of `jthread` so they are guaranteed to execute as a side effect to the dtor requesting a stop. Now the confusing part is that I can not find any guarantees that `cb3` and `cb4` are guaranteed to execute. There is nothing I could find that says that requesting stop would atomically change set the stop flag and execute all the callbacks for example. On the other hand, I looked at the [Implementation:223](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/stop_token) of `request_stop` and it seems that it does the following

- takes a lock
- set the stop flag and fetch the last registered stop callback
- release the lock
- run the callback
- release the binary semaphore (which the destructor of that callback waits on)
- tries to reacquire the lock to execute the next callback

Now finally to the question, according to the above, the execution of `cb3` and `cb4` is racing with their destructors (at least `cb3`, because `cb4` will be chosen for execution under the same lock that will be used to set the stop flag, but again I could not find that guarantee for `cb4` mentioned somewhere). So how can one use a `stop_callback` properly with a `jthread` without calling `request_stop` explicitly? you can't register the callbacks after because they will be destroyed before like `cb5` and `cb6` and you can't register them withing the thread because they are not guaranteed to execute like `cb3` and `cb4` and I do not think that it was intended to give them a longer lifetime in the convoluted way of `cb1` and `cb2`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <stop_token>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, const char * const * const argv)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    const auto _cb1 = []() -> void {
        std::cout << "cb1\n";
        std::this_thread::yield();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
    };

    const auto _cb2 = []() -> void {
        std::cout << "cb2\n";
        std::this_thread::yield();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
    };

    using CB1 =
        decltype(std::stop_callback(std::declval<std::stop_token>(), _cb1));
    using CB2 =
        decltype(std::stop_callback(std::declval<std::stop_token>(), _cb2));

    std::byte storage1[sizeof(CB1)];
    std::byte storage2[sizeof(CB2)];

    const CB1 * cb1 = nullptr;
    const CB2 * cb2 = nullptr;

    {

        std::jthread worker([](const std::stop_token & stop_token) {
            std::stop_callback cb3(stop_token, [] {
                std::cout << "cb3\n";
                std::this_thread::yield();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
            });
            std::stop_callback cb4(stop_token, [] {
                std::cout << "cb4\n";
                std::this_thread::yield();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
            });

            while (!stop_token.stop_requested())
            {
            }
        });


        cb1 = new (&storage1) std::stop_callback(worker.get_stop_token(), _cb1);

        cb2 = new (&storage2) std::stop_callback(worker.get_stop_token(), _cb2);


        std::stop_callback cb5(worker.get_stop_token(), [] {
            std::cout << "cb5\n";
            std::this_thread::yield();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
        });

        std::stop_callback cb6(worker.get_stop_token(), [] {
            std::cout << "cb6\n";
            std::this_thread::yield();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
        });

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    }

    cb1->~CB1();
    cb2->~CB2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*There is nothing I could find that says that requesting stop would atomically change set the stop flag and execute all the callbacks for example.*" Um, where did you look? [This seems pretty clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/request_stop), as [is the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/thread.stoptoken#intro-5).

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough. Where exactly does it say that it atomically sets the flag and executes all the callbacks within the same atomic operation?

Comment: What does it matter if it says "atomically" or not; it synchronizes with the `stop_requested` call. And it says that such calls don't introduce data races.

Answer (score 1):

The standard [directly states that](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/thread.stoptoken#intro-5):

> A call to `request_­stop` that returns true synchronizes with a call to `stop_requested` on an associated `stop_­token` or `stop_­source` object that returns true.

This means that a call to `stop_requested` that returns `true` "happens after" any `request_stop` that returns `true`. So your `while` loop cannot exit until a call to `request_stop` actually returns `true` to some thread. More importantly, it cannot exit until such a call *returns*.

`request_stop` is [explicitly stated](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/thread.stoptoken#stopsource.mem-4) to:

> If the request was made, the callbacks registered by associated `stop_callback` objects are synchronously called.

Being called "synchronously" means exactly that: this function will either call them on the thread requesting the stop or it will synchronize with whatever thread(s) they do get called on. The main point being that until those callbacks are finished, this function does not return.

And until this function returns, `stop_requested` will not return `true`, as previously stated.

So there is no data race. The callbacks will not be destroyed before the thread exits.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. It sounds really convincing, I'm just trying to follow it with the code and can't still wrap my  head fully around it. So inbetween line 264 and 270, the lock is released and the destructor of the current callback is unblocked by the semaphore, so could the destructor of the next callback quickly acquire the lock and deregister itself and complete the destruction process? The stop request bit is set in 232, could that not be observed directly by the thread that checks the stop requested function? I mean all what this function does is just check that this bit is s